# Server side routing with Angular for localization

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular2-routing, angular2-aot, angular-i18n

I have a Angular app that I am trying to localize. What I have so far is that all my displayed values are located in a single json file `(stringResources.json)`. After translation I will have multiple files, one for each of the languages that I want to support (i.e `en.json`, `fr.json` ect). I use AOT compilation so my options seem to be

- Use [ngx-translate](http://www.ngx-translate.com/)
- Follow [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#merge-aot)
  and pre-build a separate application for each language

What I did was to generate multiple builds by using this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-for-every-file) to output a different build for every language file, and each of these builds work well. I cannot seem to figure out **how to do the server side logic to deliver the correct package** based on url or language detection

I have 2 questions:

1) What would be the best way to make my app support l10n(localization)? It seems I have no need to go into Angular's built in i18n, since I already have the string files extracted and available?

2) What are some resources I can look into to figure out the server side logic and how to organize the structure for the different builds? I have tried changing the web.config file but that seems it will interfere with the app's routing logic

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not know much about angular.

But you might read this [article](https://medium.com/@jamuhl/i18n-frameworks-the-unfair-showdown-8d436cd6f470)...

I would recommend looking into a i18n lib that is ready to be used in different frameworks, in frontend and backend, i.e. [i18next](http://i18next.com/docs/ecosystem/)

There are some vue libs too: i.e. [ng-i18next](https://github.com/i18next/ng-i18next) or [ng2-i18next](https://github.com/actimeo/ng2-i18next) or [angular-i18next](https://github.com/Romanchuk/angular-i18next)

Further you should not only consider that you have to instrument your code (i18n) to get your app/website translated. You should think about the process too - how will you solve [continuous localization](https://medium.com/@adriano_55049/continuous-development-integration-and-localization-continuous-deployment-40ca6b9be771), how you keep track of progress, etc...

For a translation management+ system you might eg. have a look at [locize](http://locize.com) it plays well with all json based i18n frameworks... and provides a lot more than traditional systems.